# How to get touches when parent view has userInteractionEnabled set to NO in iOS

Tags: ios, uikit, touch, uiresponder

When the parent view has userInteractionEnabled=NO, its subviews will not accept touch events even if their userInteractionEnabled property is set to YES.

Is there any way to still get touch events in subviews?

Comment: You may consider this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35592676/913347

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To get a view to let touches pass-through but give its subviews handle touches, let userInteractionEnabled on that view to YES and, instead, use this snippet:

```
-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) return nil;
    else return hitView;
}
```

Source: http://cocoaheads.tumblr.com/post/2130871776/ignore-touches-to-uiview-subclass-but-not-to-its

Comment: plz describe how to use it. from where this method i need to call ??

Comment: iOS Wolf this is a UIView method https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:

Comment: Name proposal: CantTouchThisView. :)

Comment: @iOS.Wolf you need to create a custom class for the parent View for this. I hope the following code will help you.https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835097/3046381

Answer (score 6):

Swift solution- You need to have a custom view class for the parent view and add the following code to it. Please keep the parent view's user-interactions enabled.

I hope the following code will help you.

```
class MyCustomParentView: UIView {    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        if hitView == self {
            return nil
        } else {
            return hitView
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the parent view's userInteractionEnabled property to NO also implicitly sets its subviews userInteractionEnabled properties to NO as well.  I don't know of a way to get touch events to the subview using the approach that you have described, but perhaps you could create a view that simply overlays the views that you want users to interact with, but is not the parent of those views.

Answer (score -2):

A work around would be to disable the userinteraction of buttons etc to nil rather than disabling the user interaction of the whole parent view