# Superview ignores UserInteractionEnabled = NO?

Tags: ios, events, touch, superview

I have a subview thats goes onto the screen animated, and when it is on the screen, I want the superview (in my case, the view in the background), to ignore touch events. 
I tried everything but it does not work.

Is there any way to 'force' the superview to stop receiving touch events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say the superview, I assume you you mean the animating view's superview.  Apple's documentation is very unspecific about `userInteractionEnabled`, but I think that if you set it to false, it disables touch events on the specific view, but not on its subviews.  I would suggest that you do it recursively.  Here is an example of code that you could use to disable/enable ALL touch events on a view:

```
- (void)setInteraction:(BOOL)allow onView:(UIView *)aView {
    [aView setUserInteractionEnabled:allow];
    for (UIView * v in [aView subviews]) {
        [self setInteraction:allow onView:v];
    }
}
```

You could then call this on your superview `[self setInteraction:NO onView:[self superview]]`.  This would, of course, disable your touch events as well, since you are disabling them recursively on your superview.  Of course you can always re-enable your touch events `[self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]`.

Also, Apple's [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) mentions that some UI components override this method:

> **Note**: Some UIKit subclasses override this property and return a different default value. See the documentation for any class you use to determine if it returns a different value for this property.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that userInteractionEnabled affects all subviews as well.

Comment: Are you sure? I just need it on the superview and thats it.

Comment: This answer seems to clear up whether child views obey their parents' userInteractionEnabled setting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661589/how-to-get-touches-when-parent-view-has-userinteractionenabled-set-to-no-in-ios