# Can not focus on textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4

In my project, I've set a view as the root view of my app.

In the controller of this root view, I have got such a hierachy:

> rootview --[addsubview]-- foregroundView --[addsubview]-- textfield

I've done that in code instead of xib.

In that case, the textfield can not be focused. It seems that nothing happened when I click the textfield on the screen. But if I modified like that :

> rootview --[addsubview]-- foregroundView
>
> rootview --[addsubview]-- textfield

Everything worked fine.

Since I wanna make foregroundView and textfield as a group, I prefer to use the former style.  Do any have idea of this? Thanks very much.

Here is the core source code for my trouble:

```
//it's a viewController.m , it's view has been set as the root view for the app.
self.foregroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 140, 290, 250)]; 
UIImage *foregroundImage = [XYZImageProcessor resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Texture0203.jpg"] toSize:CGSizeMake(275, 250)];
[self.view addSubview:self.foregroundView ];
self.nickNameTextField = [self.class customTextFieldMake:CGRectMake(80, 200, 150, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:self.nickNameTextField];
//if I change it to    [self.foregroundView addSubview:self.nickNameTextField],the textfield can not be focused.
```

Comment: What do you mean 'won't focus'? Does the keyboard appear at all?

Comment: can you post the code where you build the view hierarchy?

Comment: 'won't focus' means when I touch the textfield on the screen, keyboard can not appear. I'll add some source code now, sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sound as if your `foregroundView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO.  This doesn't just mean that `foregroundView` does not receive touch events - none of its subviews do either.  See [How to get touches when parent view has userInteractionEnabled set to NO in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4661589/1318452).  (Short answer: you can't.)

So, try setting `[foregroundView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]` when building your views.

If `foregroundView` implements its own `hitTest:withEvent:` it could also prevent interaction with its subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in **viewWillAppear:**

```
[desiredField becomeFirstResponder];
```

By making the field the first responder, it have focus and the keyboard will be displayed.

Comment: It's not a good idea to call -becomeFirstResponder. The documentation for the method specifically states "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly." https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSResponder

Comment: Thanks:). becomeFirstResponder will get the keyboard, but it appears at the beginning, without my control. I still can not focus on it after quitting from the keyboard.  makeFirstResponder should be invoked in a NSWindow, that may not suite my case.