# Why User Interaction Enabled is Necessary for the Target too Instead of Just the Button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, user-interaction

```
UIButton * newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
newButton.imageObject= someImage;
UIImage * imagePut  = someImage.imageBlob;
imagePut = [imagePut roundedCornerImage:20 borderSize:0];
[newButton setImage:imagePut forState:UIControlStateNormal];

newButton.frame= CGRectMake(column * self.distanceBetweenButton +marginBetweenButtons, row *self.distanceBetweenButton+marginBetweenButtons, self.sizeOfButtons, self.sizeOfButtons);
newButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
PO(@(newButton.userInteractionEnabled));
newButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someImageGotPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
PO(@([newButton allControlEvents]));
PO(newButton.allTargets);
[self.collectionOfButton addObject:newButton];
```

Simple button. The problem is someImageGotPressed is never called.

The newButton of course have userInteractionEnabled by default. However, someImageGotPressed is still not called.

The target is a UITableViewCell. I turned off the userinteractionenabled for that uiTableViewCell because I expect people to interact with the button.

I turned that back to on and it works.

However, something puzzles me. The target in addTarget can be anything right. It doesn't even have to be a UIView or UIViewController. So why the hell the userInteractionEnabled for target matters at all?

Is this because UITableViewCell is the superview of the button and turning off userInteractionEnabled of a view will turn that off in all it's superView or that sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you set the super view's `userInteractionEnabled` (`UITableViewCell`) to NO, that will cause ignoring all the touches event to its subviews too.

Comment: The answer here is correct but doesn't provide a solution.
Here is a possible solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661589/how-to-get-touches-when-parent-view-has-userinteractionenabled-set-to-no-in-ios)