# UIToolbar - Allow interaction below toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a custom `UIToolbar` in my `UINavigationController`, with a custom background image.
The image is half transparent on the right.  The problem that I'm having is that some views have buttons on the bottom right and the bottom part of those buttons cannot be tapped because the toolbar blocks it.

I cannot set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` on the `UIToolBar`, because the bar contains `UIBarButtonItem`s which need to remain interactive.

Is there a way to make the bar ignore tap inputs (but not the `UIBarButtonItem`s)?

Comment: What are "tab inputs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on the toolbar, but override `hitTest:point` as described in [How to get touches when parent view has userInteractionEnabled set to NO in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661589/how-to-get-touches-when-parent-view-has-userinteractionenabled-set-to-no-in-ios).  This makes it ignore any touches on itself, but accept any touches on any subviews (`UIBarButtonItem`s in your case):

```
- (id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (hitView == self) {
        return nil;

    } else {
        return hitView;
    }
}
```

Note that this would require you to subclass `UIToolbar`.