# User Interaction enabled No Only to the parent

Tags: ios, xcode

I have one scroll view (`UserInteractionEnabled = No`) with one image view as its subview.
I am assigning tap gesture to imageview but it is not working even if imageview is `UserInteractionEnabled` because Its parent (ScrollView) is not.
How can I resolve this conflict.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661589/how-to-get-touches-when-parent-view-has-userinteractionenabled-set-to-no-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to disable user interaction on a scroll view. If you want to block the scrolling, disable it using the `scrollEnabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `scroll view (UserInteractionEnabled = No)` because it will set to all its subViews.
hope it will work.