# UIView blocking UIScrollView's gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout

Hi I have a `UIView` on top of a `UIScrollView` like this. The `UIView` is a container that is itself transparent but has many subviews which are not.

```
-------------------------
-   UIScrollView        -
-                       -
-     -------------     -   
-     -  UIView   -     -   
-     -------------     -     
-------------------------
```

The `UIView` is transparent but it prevents the `UIScrollView` from scrolling when touched. Some of the subviews are buttons so they have tap gestures that override the scrolling action but the transparent gaps in the frame of the `UIView` still blocks the scrolling gesture. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I would still like to use it as a container to hold my other subviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set userInteractionEnabled to **NO** hence you want it intractable. I think the right way is to subclass a UIView and override `- pointInside: withEvent:` like below.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint localPoint = [self convertPoint:point fromView:self];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview pointInside:localPoint withEvent:event]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Use this view you can interact with subviews inside the view and scroll scroll view if not touch on subviews.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers guys. But I found this solution which worked well for me:

[How to get touches when parent view has userInteractionEnabled set to NO in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661589/how-to-get-touches-when-parent-view-has-userinteractionenabled-set-to-no-in-ios)

Answer (score -1):

Set `userInteractionEnabled` to `FALSE` on your view inside the scroll view.

```
myView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this causes all the buttons in my container to not fire. Is there another method that you know that could prevent that? Thanks for helping though!

Comment: You could add actions (`void` or `IBAction`) to those buttons instead of recognizers. That should work...

Comment: Thanks for showing me this option, I was able to find a solution from it.

Comment: Happy to help, glad you figured it out.