# UIButton in UIView not responding to touch events despite userInteractionEnabled = true

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, uibutton

I'm having a tough time with this issue. I have a custom UIView, that contains a UIImageView and a UIButton. The custom UIView is called a PPButton, and the code for adding these controls is below. One thing to note is that I am overwriting drawRect, which shouldn't effect what is going on here.

```
private func addSubviews() {

    let buttonFontMultipllier : CGFloat = 4.5 / 10.0
    let buttonFontSize = (self.subRect!.height) * buttonFontMultipllier

    self.ppButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as? UIButton
    self.ppButton!.setTitle(self.ppButtonTitle!, forState: .Normal)
    self.ppButton!.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.ppButton!.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Formata-BoldCondensed", size: buttonFontSize)
    self.ppButton!.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Left
    self.ppButton!.addTarget(self, action:"buttonWasTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.ppButton!.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.ppButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    self.ppButton!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    self.ppButton!.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    self.ppImage = UIImageView()
    self.ppImage!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.ppImage!.userInteractionEnabled = false

    self.ppImage!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    self.ppImage!.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    self.ppButtonView!.addSubview(self.ppButton!)
    self.ppButtonView!.addSubview(self.ppImage!)

    self.ppButtonView!.bringSubviewToFront(self.ppButton!)
    self.ppButtonView!.sendSubviewToBack(self.ppImage!)
    self.ppButtonView!.userInteractionEnabled = false;

    self.addSubview(self.ppButtonView!)

    superview!.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
}
```

These buttons are added to another custom View, which is being added to a custom view controller. The code for adding the PPButtons to the custom HomeView is below.

```
func addSubviews() {

    self.homeLogo = UIImageView()
    self.homeLogo!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.addSubview(self.homeLogo!)

    self.orderBtn = PPButton(title: "Order")
    self.orderBtn!.delegate = self
    self.orderBtn!.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.addSubview(self.orderBtn!)

    self.findUsBtn = PPButton(title: "Find Us")
    self.findUsBtn!.delegate = self
    self.orderBtn!.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.addSubview(self.findUsBtn!)

    self.menuBtn = PPButton(title: "Menu")
    self.menuBtn!.delegate = self
    self.orderBtn!.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.addSubview(self.menuBtn!)

    self.clubPatronBtn = PPButton(title: "Club Patron")
    self.clubPatronBtn!.delegate = self
    self.orderBtn!.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.addSubview(self.clubPatronBtn!)

    self.loginButton = UIButton()
    self.loginButton!.setTitle(String("Login or Create an Account").uppercaseString, forState: .Normal)
    self.loginButton!.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.loginButton!.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Formata-BoldCondensed", size: 18.0)
    self.loginButton!.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.loginButton!.addTarget(self, action: Selector("testFunc"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.addSubview(self.loginButton!)
}
```

When I try to click the buttons, the targets aren't firing for the PPButtons. Further, they aren't firing for the loginButton, which is just a simple UIButton. All of these are being added programmatically. I'm sure there is something small I am doing wrong.

Also, I ran a check to see of all my views, starting at the ViewController, which ones has the userInteractionEnabled set to true. The function and output are below. Please help!

```
func logViewHierarchy(view: UIView, num: Int) {

    var index = num
    for i in 0..<index {
        print("\t")
    }

    index = index + 1
    println("\(NSStringFromClass(view.dynamicType)) userInteractionEnabled: \(view.userInteractionEnabled)")
    for subview in view.subviews {
        self.logViewHierarchy(subview as! UIView, num: index)
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
UIView userInteractionEnabled: false
     UIImageView userInteractionEnabled: false
     _UILayoutGuide userInteractionEnabled: true
     _UILayoutGuide userInteractionEnabled: true
     Pizza_Patron.HomeView userInteractionEnabled: false
          UIImageView userInteractionEnabled: false
          Pizza_Patron.PPButton userInteractionEnabled: false
               UIView userInteractionEnabled: false
                    UIImageView userInteractionEnabled: false
                    UIButton userInteractionEnabled: true
                         UIButtonLabel userInteractionEnabled: false
          Pizza_Patron.PPButton userInteractionEnabled: true
               UIView userInteractionEnabled: false
                    UIImageView userInteractionEnabled: false
                    UIButton userInteractionEnabled: true
                         UIButtonLabel userInteractionEnabled: false
          Pizza_Patron.PPButton userInteractionEnabled: true
               UIView userInteractionEnabled: false
                    UIImageView userInteractionEnabled: false
                    UIButton userInteractionEnabled: true
                         UIButtonLabel userInteractionEnabled: false
          Pizza_Patron.PPButton userInteractionEnabled: true
               UIView userInteractionEnabled: false
                    UIImageView userInteractionEnabled: false
                    UIButton userInteractionEnabled: true
                         UIButtonLabel userInteractionEnabled: false
          UIButton userInteractionEnabled: true
               UIButtonLabel userInteractionEnabled: false
```

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like your top level view as well as a few ones lower down have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `false`. This cascades down so if a superview has interaction turned off, its subviews won't receive interaction events.

You could reorder your hierarchy if you want to keep some of those view's interactions disabled, just turn interaction on for those superviews or try something like this and pass through the events:

[How to get touches when parent view has userInteractionEnabled set to NO in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661589/how-to-get-touches-when-parent-view-has-userinteractionenabled-set-to-no-in-ios)

Comment: Everything I have read has actual indicated differently than what you are telling me. If I set UserInteractionEnabled to true at the top level, that object will intercept all touch events. I guess from that point, I should override touchesBegan or something.

Comment: Yep! My parent stack view had it disabled. Solved problem for me.